# The integral $\int_{o}^{\infty} e^{-3t} cos(4(t-5))u(t-5) dt$ using laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

$$\int_{o}^{\infty} e^{-3t} cos(4(t-5))u(t-5) dt$$
I need to find the laplace transform. Do i consider it as a convolution integral or as f(t)/t and work accordingly. Thank you.

Edit: It turns out that its similar in shape to the definition of the laplace transform ,but rather than putting an s in the exponent of the e, we have a 3 so we solve it as if its an s then substitute s with 3.

Comment: When the integral is evaluated you receive a constant. (according to wolfram alpha: $\frac{3}{25e^{15}}$). How are you supposed to lapance-transform a constant?

Comment: Your integral is just the Laplace transform of a shifted cosinus function $
F(s)=e^{-5s}\frac{s}{s^2+16}
$ at $s=3$, i.e. $F(3)=e^{-15}\frac{3}{25}$. So what do you expect?